Cross-compiling with VS code on Mac for Windows VM
I have been building my C++ app on the Mac, for the Mac. But soon I would like to be able to make this simple game available on multiple platforms. I got prematurely excited when I saw that Parallels has provided an extension to work with Visual Studio code on Mac. But a closer examination shows that this extension is only icing on the cake. What I can't find anywhere is a "Take it from the top" document describing how I might cross-compile from Mac to Windows and run the product in a Parallels virtual machine that is running on the Mac.
Issues and questions:

I know that I want to edit on the Mac, keeping the source all in one place.
I think that I want to compile on the Mac. If so, there's a whole issue of downloading Windows headers and libraries into some sort of compilation "sandbox" on the Mac. How is that done?
I hope that, having built on the Mac, I can arrange things so that the F5 run command automatically transfers the built product into the VM and runs it there. Is this possible?
Maybe even remote debugging?

This is too broad a question to expect a truckload of answers here. I'm really asking for references to one or more "Take it from the top" documents where I might read up on this whole concept. Please tell me they exist…!

(2) can be done in two ways. Either you find a version of MinGW for Mac (I'm not a Mac user, so no idea where to get it) (which will include both some executables, and headers/libraries), OR you find MinGW for any other OS (e.g Windows versions are easier to come by) (which will include executables you can't natively run on Mac, but also the same headers/libraries) and then use a regular build of Clang (I'm not sure if Apple Clang is good for this, if not there's a way to get the normal non-apple version on Mac) like this: clang++ --target=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --sysroot=path/to/mingw.

...Clang will then use mingw headers/libs for cross-compilation. (You might need to tune the flags a bit, such as -stdlib=libstdc++ vs -stdlib=libc++, but it's not hard.) I prefer the second option because Windows builds of MinGW are easier to come by (mingw versions in various linux distros are often outdated), and also because MSYS2 is a thing (they provide a collection of prebuilt mingw libs you can use, including third-party ones). I maintain scripts to download those mingw headers/libs from them. The script should work on mac.

...There's some other things in there that likely won't work on mac, but they are optional (you only need the make install part). You can point your Clang to the downloaded libs with the flags above. If you want to build with CMake, you'll also need to write a CMake toolchain file (you can use this one if you remove the 'crosscompiling=false' part, because that assumes binfmt_misc is enabled to pretend we're not cross-compiling).

As for (3), it shouldn't be hard. The first thing that comes to mind is installing [SSH] onto the Windows WM (I found this specific SSH server to work best), and then writing a script that copies your build over SSH and uses it to run it.

Thank you so much, @HolyBlackCat. That's really helpful! But did you forget a link to the ssh server in your fourth comment?

Ah, yes, here: https://bitvise.com/ssh-server I tried a few Windows ssh servers a while back, and this was the only sane one, but you should probably do your own googling too.
